# Parallel table update using python multiprocessing (PostGIS/PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, psycopg2

Hi I have been using the multiprocessing approach for updating a huge postgis table from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555680/create-db-connection-and-maintain-on-multiple-processes-multiprocessing/30706879#30706879) and it works quite well, but my table doesn't seem to get updated unless I add a `commit;` statement at the end of

```
procQuery = 'UPDATE city SET gid_fkey = gid FROM country  WHERE ST_within((SELECT the_geom FROM city WHERE city_id = %s), country.the_geom) AND city_id = %s' % (self.a, self.a)
```

like

```
procQuery = 'UPDATE city SET gid_fkey = gid FROM country  WHERE ST_within((SELECT the_geom FROM city WHERE city_id = %s), country.the_geom) AND city_id = %s;commit;' % (self.a, self.a)
```

what could be the problem here?

Comment: In what way does it not make sense to you ? It is an SQL thing to `commit` an `update`, `insert` or `delete` query. Maybe you think your database transaction object has autocommit set to true. Might be worth it to check this first.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved by setting the connection to autommit = True

```
class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):

    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
    self.task_queue = task_queue
    self.result_queue = result_queue
    self.pyConn = psycopg2.connect(**connstring)
    self.pyConn.autocommit = True


def run(self):
    proc_name = self.name
    while True:
        next_task = self.task_queue.get()
        if next_task is None:
            print 'Tasks Complete'
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            break            
        answer = next_task(connection=self.pyConn)
        self.task_queue.task_done()
        self.result_queue.put(answer)
    return
```